# Implementing "Expand/Collapse all" with DisclosurePanels in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a lot of DisclosurePanels nested one inside another (or may not be nested either). I want to implement "expand all" and "collapse all" buttons. 
Please suggest a clean way to do so.

Note: I tried looking a bit onto Event handling in GWT but got a bit confused with things. I am not sure if I could use Custom Events for my case. It seems that I can define a custom event and its handler and do the addHandler() stuff but in the class that'll implement the handler interface I don't have the instance of DisclosurePanel that'll allow me to use setOpen() property of disclosure panel.

Comment: can you please provide a piece of code ?

Comment: I have nothing written down specifically for this feature. Since I do not know how to proceed (which mechanism to use) I have kind of done no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to introspect the Widget hierarchy. Starting from the topmost parent disclosure panel, look at all of the child widgets, check if they are DisclosurePanels, and either open/close them. This could be potentially bad for performance if there are many widgets, but you could try anyways.

This code hasn't been tested, but might do what you need:

```
void openChildren(Widget w, boolean isOpen){
    if(w instanceof DisclosurePanel){
        ((DisclosurePanel)w).setOpen(isOpen);
    }

    if(w instanceof HasWidgets){
        for(Widget ch : ((HasWidgets)w)){
            openChildren(ch, isOpen);
        }
    }

    if(w instanceof HasOneWidget){
        openChildren(((HasOneWidget)w).getWidget(), isOpen);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah this kind of makes sense. I'll try it and get back! Thanks.!

Comment: This worked.! Thanks a lot.!
One thing though... The last if block with HasOneWidget didn't make sense to me so I tried without it and it works just fine without it.

Comment: Hey, @peterd there is only one implementation of `HasOneWidget` that I know of and that is a `SimplePanel`. You might not be using any, but I included it for completeness. I would like for GWT to add a "WidgetVisitor" that would encompass all of the interfaces in the widget tree, but alas they don't use github yet, so I can't be bothered to contribute it... :(